# Gradle 4 Java 11

Tags: java, gradle, sonarqube

I have an Android project with Gradle 4 that I’m trying to analyze with Sonar.
The sonar tasks must run with Java 11 so I configure the java version on 11 in my CI of Azure Devops but I receive this error:

Could not determine java version from '11.0.12'.

I saw that Gradle 4 is not compatible with Java 11 and that version 9 of sonar is not compatible with Java 8.

How to Perform Sonar Analysis on a Gradle 4 Project

Comment: Is there no way you could upgrade Gradle? The current version is 7.2....

Comment: No for now I do not want to update the version of gradle

Comment: @dna, maybe you should use, ib this case, the lover version of SonarQube?

Answer (score 2):

The minimum version of Gradle that supports Java 11 is `5.0`.

You would need to upgrade to version `7.0` or above for [Android](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html#android).

Source: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html

Comment: not 100% true... gradle version 4.10.3 supports java 11

Answer (score 1):

as @Asif A Fasih mentioned, Gradle added official support for Java 11 with Gradle `5.0` - but they also provided a patch version for `4.10` which works with Java 11 - `4.10.3`

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 4.10.3
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2018-12-05 00:50:54 UTC
Revision:     e76905e3a1034e6f724566aeb985621347ff43bc

Kotlin DSL:   1.0-rc-6
Kotlin:       1.2.61
Groovy:       2.4.15
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.11 compiled on March 23 2018
JVM:          11.0.6 (SAP SE 11.0.6+10-LTS-sapmachine)
OS:           Linux 5.4.0-88-generic amd64
```

i am sadly running this setup on multiple projects